# Why my canvas doesn't draw more than 100*100 pixels?

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I'm writing an application that draws a rectangle where the user clicks. However my canvas only works in first 100*100 pixels in upper left corner of the screen. When the application is launched it works fine but after the user's first touch it only works in the upper left 100*100 pixels of the screen.

```
package com.example.sudokutest;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static int x=0;
public static int y=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new Myview(MainActivity.this));

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Display dispaly=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size=new Point();
    dispaly.getSize(size);

    x=size.x;
    y=size.y-40; //Subtracting the NotificationBar from height not accurately


}
```

}

```
public class Myview extends View {

 public Rect selRect = new Rect();

    public Myview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        selRect.set(0,0,300,400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_background));
        canvas.drawRect(selRect,paint);
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int a = (int)event.getX();
        final int b = (int)event.getY();

        int eventaction = event.getAction();

        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),(CharSequence)("ACTION_DOWN AT COORDS "+"X: "+a+" Y: "+b),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selRect.set(a,b,100,100);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "MOVE "+"X: "+a+" Y: "+b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+a+" Y: "+b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

this is the xml file. it's blank and it is supposed to be filled with the ondraw method.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sudokutest.MainActivity" >
```

Comment: show your layout xml

Comment: there is nothing on the layout. it's just a blank page

Comment: @Gavriel  posted the layout

Comment: where's the canvas in the layout?

Comment: i don't know i haven't put the canvas in the layout. how should i put it?

Comment: what do you draw on?

Comment: actually i'm using another class to call the myview class. i will post the main class right now.@Gavriel

Comment: i just added mainactivity too.@Gavriel

Answer (score 0):

in onTouchEvent you call this in ACTION_DOWN:

```
selRect.set(a,b,100,100);
```

And you never reset it.

Comment: thanks Gavriel i did find out the problem. However i may need your opinion again later. thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your custom canvas class over another view, and are using a relative or frame layout, just add your canvas on top...

Assuming you have your main RelativeLayout named main_layout, and your CustomView, called drawable, you can add drawable to the main_layout like so...

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            main_layout.addView(drawable, params);
```